# Smart casting not working when statement is refactored. How to solve?

Tags: kotlin

I have something simple below (I use when instead of if, as I simplified from some code that uses when)

```
fun simplePresent(presentable: Presentable?) {
    when {
        presentable != null -> execute(presentable)
        else -> skip()
    }
}

fun execute(presentable: Presentable) { // Do something }
```

It's all good. But when I refactor the checking code out into Function

```
fun simplePresent(presentable: Presentable?) {
    when {
        hasPresentable(presentable) -> execute(presentable)
        else -> skip()
    }
}

fun execute(presentable: Presentable) { // Do something }
fun hasPresentable(presentable: Presentable?) = presentable != null
```

the smart casting to non-null fail for the value pass to `execute` function, causing a compile time error reporting `required Presentable found Presentable?`

How could I prevent that error, while I still retain my refactor code?

Answer (score 0):

Functions are meant to be independent to each other. There is just no constraint to enforce `hasPresentable` to return true iff presentable is not null at type level.

So it's kind of impossible without Kotlin team deciding to enhance the type system.

Why not using something like `presentable?.execute() ?: skip()` instead?

If you want to do more checking in `hasPresentable` you can do this:

```
fun checkPresentable(presentable: Presentable?): Presentable? =
  presentable?.takeIf { do your check here }

fun simplePresent(presentable: Presentable?) =
  checkPresentable(presentable)?.execute() ?: skip()

fun Presentable.execute() {  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't do that, because in my actual code, there are more `when cases`, hence a single `execute` would not suffice. And the comparison is having more than just one `presentable`.